# Error with ctable package after updating MikTex

Tags: errors, miktex-update

I had a tex file that was compiling fine until I updated MikTex a few nights ago (I updated in both admin and user modes). I now keep getting the following error when I try to compile:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \AtBeginEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ... 

                                                   l.1752   \csgappto{@begin@#1@hook}}
```

When I type H, it says it can't provide further information. So I keep pressing return, and it keeps compiling until it finally finishes with:

```
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 11687 bytes).
SyncTeX written on MWE.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on MWE.log.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Rebecca\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I've posted the document's log file at the bottom.

The ctable package seems to be the only one needed to reproduce the error in my MWE below. But everything was working before MikTek was updated. This is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.3.29)  29 MAR 2022 15:07
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C:/Users/Rebecca/Documents/1.Carleton_PhD/00.rebecca_SVN_repository/My_Public
ations/Journal_Papers/2021-05-13_P1-JBPS/MWE.tex

(C:/Users/Rebecca/Documents/1.Carleton_PhD/00.rebecca_SVN_repository/My_Publica
tions/Journal_Papers/2021-05-13_P1-JBPS/MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctable\ctable.sty
Package: ctable 2015/10/17 v1.31 ctable package for flexible typesetting of tab
le and figure floats using key/value directives

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193


! LaTeX Error: Command \AtBeginEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1752   \csgappto{@begin@#1@hook}}
                                   
? H
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
? H
Sorry, I already gave what help I could...
Maybe you should try asking a human?
An error might have occurred before I noticed any problems.
``If all else fails, read the instructions.''

? 

Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtBeginEnvironment' will not work.


! LaTeX Error: Command \AtEndEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1766   \csgappto{@end@#1@hook}}
                                 
? 

Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtEndEnvironment' will not work.


! LaTeX Error: Command \BeforeBeginEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1780   \csgappto{@beforebegin@#1@hook}}
                                         
? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \AfterEndEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1792   \csgappto{@afterend@#1@hook}}
                                      
? 

Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AfterEndEnvironment' will not work.

) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count194
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen139
\ar@mcellbox=\box50
\extrarowheight=\dimen140
\NC@list=\toks18
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
\ar@cellbox=\box51
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen141
\TX@old@table=\dimen142
\TX@old@col=\dimen143
\TX@target=\dimen144
\TX@delta=\dimen145
\TX@cols=\count195
\TX@ftn=\toks19
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen146
\lightrulewidth=\dimen147
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen148
\belowrulesep=\dimen149
\belowbottomsep=\dimen150
\aboverulesep=\dimen151
\abovetopsep=\dimen152
\cmidrulesep=\dimen153
\cmidrulekern=\dimen154
\defaultaddspace=\dimen155
\@cmidla=\count196
\@cmidlb=\count197
\@aboverulesep=\dimen156
\@belowrulesep=\dimen157
\@thisruleclass=\count198
\@lastruleclass=\count199
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen158
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\rotating.sty
Package: rotating 2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen159
\Gin@req@width=\dimen160
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@r@tfl@t=\count266
\rotFPtop=\skip51
\rotFPbot=\skip52
\rot@float@box=\box52
\rot@mess@toks=\toks20
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/transparent\transparent.sty
Package: transparent 2019/11/29 v1.4 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)


(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
))
\@CTframesep=\dimen161
\@dfltCTframesep=\dimen162
\@CTframerule=\dimen163
\@dfltCTframerule=\dimen164
\@CTwidth=\dimen165
\@dfltCTwidth=\dimen166
\@CTcaptionskip=\dimen167
\@dfltCTcaptionskip=\dimen168
\@CTmaxwidth=\dimen169
\@dfltCTmaxwidth=\dimen170
\@CTmincapwidth=\dimen171
\@dfltCTmincapwidth=\dimen172
\@CTfooterwidth=\dimen173
\@dfltCTfooterwidth=\dimen174
\@CTw=\dimen175
\@CTfloatwidth=\dimen176
\@CToldsep=\dimen177
\@CToldrule=\dimen178
\CT@t=\box53
\@CTcurftwidth=\dimen179
)
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \let \AtEndPreamble \@firstofone \@endpreamblehook \pr...
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
? 

(C:\Users\Rebecca\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdft
ex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count267
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
)
No file MWE.aux.
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count268
\scratchdimen=\dimen180
\scratchbox=\box55
\nofMPsegments=\count269
\nofMParguments=\count270
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count271
\MPscratchDim=\dimen181
\MPnumerator=\count272
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count273
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
)) [1

{C:/Users/Rebecca/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (MWE.a
ux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 6 (\begingroup)
### bottom level 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2972 strings out of 478571
 46257 string characters out of 2851916
 340515 words of memory out of 3000000
 21157 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 85i,5n,90p,733b,692s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 11687 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I get no error in texlive, did you update miktex in user and admin, you seem to have incompatible packages, can you show the log file from that test document?

Comment: the log file from your test file is only a couple of hundred lines so you should be able to add it to the question marked with `\`\`\``  as a code block

Comment: I get no error using recent MiKTeX.

Comment: @David-carlisle thanks, I've posted the log file to the question.
Thanks Zarko - that's good to know...

Comment: etoolbox is outdated, you have etoolbox 2018/08/19, current is etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how do I do that? When I check for updates in MikTex, it says there are none.

Comment: do you check in the console in *admin* mode?

Comment: yes, I did, it also had no new updates.

Comment: there must be updates, so probably you are not doing the check correctly. Did you open the console as user and switched there to the admin mode?

Comment: I am using the MikTex GUI to check for updates. Is that ok to use or should I use the terminal?
Yes I opened it and clicked "Switch to Admin mode", then I checked for updates and it said "no new package updates, try again tomorrow". 

However when I search for" etoolbox" in the Packages tab, it doesn't look like etoolbox is installed, so I'm confused. Something is wrong. Maybe I should try updates in the terminal?

Comment: are you sure that you have only one miktex installation? What does the console say in the settings about the directories?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have another installation. In Directories it says my Install is in "C:\Program Files\MiKTex 2.9" and that the Config,Data is in "C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX2.9", which is another directory.

Comment: FYI I tried installing the etoolbox package manually, using the console, and now my compiling of the MWE works! I'm not sure why it wasn't recognizing the package etoolbox that was already there.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was an out-of-date etoolbox package that the MiKTeX console was not updating, in either User or Admin mode. It was pointed out in the comments below my question that: "etoolbox is outdated, you have etoolbox 2018/08/19, current is etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k"

The answer, in my case, was to navigate to Packages in the MiKTeX Console, and manually add etoolbox (which didn't appear as "installed" for some reason).